# Docker-compose Fails due to no space left on device

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start some docker containers, but docker-compose up -d fails because no space left on device, i've tried cleaning all unused images, volumes and containers but i still have the same problem.
Here's the issue.
[docker compose error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkcHM.png)

Comment: If I assume you have enough space, try to reload the docker daemon: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: Well, it means then you still do not have enough disk space. Clear all unused stuff (`docker system prune`) and check the remaining space on your disk (`du -sh /var/snap/docker`).

Comment: here's the result of `du -sh /var/snap/docker` 
`2.7G    /var/snap/docker`

Comment: Well you might it might be not enough for what you want to run. If you have enough space on your other partitions you can resize your partition with `cfdisk` for instance

Answer (score 2):

The problem with docker container's is that it takes alot of memory space within or system so if you don't have enough memory space docker will throw an exception about no space left.

You should always use `sudo docker system prune` command to avoid those errors, Before building any new image don't forget to use this command;

This command will remove all images, containers & volumes from your system.

Don't forget to use `sudo docker system prune`

Answer (score 0):

`docker system prune` works but you need to use `sudo`

Comment: Not really. If you need to use sudo, it means you didn't grant root privileges to docker. Create a group for docker: `sudo groupadd docker`, and add your user to the group: `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`. Reboot to apply changes